# How to change grid row color in wicket?

Tags: colors, wicket, row

I want to change grid row color when I click a row in Wicket. 

Do  you have any suggestion?

Comment: What row? What Wicket component? My guess would be to use just normal HTML features (CSS,..)

Comment: Please show the existing code producing the grid.

Answer (score 2):

Without actually seeing your code it's difficult to tell what is the more suitable way of doing this for you.

If you want to change to a specific color known at page generation time, do it client-side (javascript). 
Make sure the grid row has a `wicket:id` so that Wicket can have control over it. Add it as a `WebMarkupContainer` if you haven't got it. Add a `SimpleAttributeModifier` for the `onclick` attribute that will change the css class of the element. For instance:

```
rowMarkupContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("row");
String javascript = "this.setAttribute('class', 'myClass');";
rowMarkupContainer.add(new SimpleAttributeModifier("onclick", javascript);
```

Where `myClass` is a CSS class that uses a new color.

Alternatively, you can always *hardcode* the `onclick` event handler in the HTML without specifying a `wicket:id`.